# Always got "EsHadoopInvalidRequest: null" when using spark & elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

My scenario: read data from elasticsearch then do some calculations, the final result of the calculation is stored elasticsearch.

I use a small amount of data to test is successful,But switch to big amount of data always occur this error. I am really confused

spark version : 1.6.1
elasticsearch version : 2.3.1

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 37, 10.10.150.231): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: null
c2NhbjsxOzMxMzY0OlpFSWVjWnh5Ukxtd1diMUdoVXJINVE7MTt0b3RhbF9oaXRzOjQ2NzIwOw==
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:478)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:436)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:426)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.scroll(RestClient.java:496)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:454)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.package$SparkRDDFunctions.saveToEs(package.scala:37)
    at BothwayForPU$.main(BothwayForPU.scala:82)
    at BothwayForPU.main(BothwayForPU.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: null
c2NhbjsxOzMxMzY0OlpFSWVjWnh5Ukxtd1diMUdoVXJINVE7MTt0b3RhbF9oaXRzOjQ2NzIwOw==
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:478)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:436)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:426)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.scroll(RestClient.java:496)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:454)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I find the reason about this problem finally. There is memory leak in my code.  No memory available in worker node.

Comment: did you know how to solve the problem? I also have it.